# Runtime exception method not found even though method is define in class

Tags: java

I have a POJO class define in my project and It was working perfectly until I added two new variables (processVisa,processMastercard) and set/get methods. Now the issue is when I accessed this method from a different class I got a method not found runtime error even though it gets compile and built successfully. Here is my POJO class.

```
public class SubmitterRequest{

    private int numOfBatch;
    private boolean processVisa;
    private boolean processMastercard;

    public int getNumOfBatch() {
        return numOfBatch;
    }

    public void setNumOfBatch(int numOfBatch) {
        this.numOfBatch = numOfBatch;
    }

    public boolean isProcessVisa() {
        return processVisa;
    }

    public void setProcessVisa(boolean processVisa) {
        this.processVisa = processVisa;
    }

    public boolean isProcessMastercard() {
        return processMastercard;
    }

    public void setProcessMastercard(boolean processMastercard) {
        this.processMastercard = processMastercard;
    }
}
```

let's say in class B

```
SubmitterRequest submitterRequest = new SubmitterRequest();

submitterRequest.setProcessVisa(true);
submitterRequest.setProcessMastercard(true);
```

I have checked build path twice and also verified .class file at runtime which includes these methods.

Comment: What is the exception exactly says? Can you print stacktrace here?

Comment: Which Java do you use? If it is Java 9 and higher are those classes in the same module? If not do you import one module into another?

Comment: @EmreSavcı  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sdk.updater.model.SubmitterRequest.setProcessVisa(Z)V

Comment: @Ivan I am using Java 8 and classes are in the same module.